# Cambiar texto de Sign in button en android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-auth

Estoy haciendo tratando de cambiar el texto del botón sign in que viene en la implementación de

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

Este boton lo programo en el xml de un activity de la siguiente manera:

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Pero por el prederterminado del texto es Sign In y el logo de Google de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Antes que nada ya intente poner

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignOutButton
```

Pero no esta librería no existe, también intente

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="out"/>
```

Pero esta librería tampoco existe.

Ademas de colocar un imagenbutton pero tampoco deja modificar el texto.

Agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar lo siguiente

```
protected void setGoogleButtonText(SignInButton signInButton, String buttonText) {
    // Encontrar el texto que esta dentro del boton
    for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);

        if (v instanceof TextView) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            tv.setText(buttonText);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Simplemente le pasas el boton como parametro y el texto que queres poner adentro

### Uso

```
setGoogleButtonText(sign_in_button,"out")
```

### Notas

Es importante que tomes esto con cautela, cualquier cambio en la libreria de google puede hacer que esto no funcione mas, mi recomendacion es que crees tu propio boton sign in personalizado